# Handlebars external markup with PHP ajax

Tags: jquery, handlebars.js

I would like to keep all my template markup files in an external html file while using `jQuery` ajax to communicate with the server using `PHP`.  PHP will return only variable data in a `json` object.

Q: How can I organize this so that using the code below my html template is in an external file?

jquery:

> ```
>    $.ajax({ type: "POST",
>             async: false,
>             url: "ajaxHandler.php",// normally the template, but i need php for dB connect
>             dataType: "json",
>             success: function(data){
>                 var aaa = data.aaa,
>                         bbb = data.bbb,
>                         ccc = data.ccc;
>                 console.log(aaa+' '+bbb+' '+ccc);       
>             }
>         });
> ```

php:

> $aaa = 1; 
>       $bbb = 'bbb'; 
>       $ccc = "$aaa $bbb"; 
>       echo json_encode(array( "aaa"=>$aaa, "bbb"=>$bbb, "ccc"=>$ccc ));

my index.html contains:

> ```
>   <table class="entries">
>             <script id="template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
>                             <tr>
>                                     <td>{{aaa}}</td>
>                                     <td>{{bbb}}</td>
>                                     <td>{{ccc}}</td>
>                             </tr>
>             </script>
>     </table>
> ```

but i would like to keep this in an external file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll either need to [precompile your templates](http://handlebarsjs.com/precompilation.html) or [load and compile the `.hbs` files with Ajax when requested](http://berzniz.com/post/24743062344/handling-handlebars-js-like-a-pro). After that you can just get the template from `Handlebars.templates`, populate it with your data and append it to your entries

`yourtemplate.hbs`

```
<tr>
  <td>{{aaa}}</td>
  <td>{{bbb}}</td>
  <td>{{ccc}}</td>
</tr>
```

`JavaScript`

```
   $.ajax({ type: "POST",
            async: true,
            url: "ajaxHandler.php",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                var template = Handlebars.template["yourtemplate.hbs"],
                    html = template(data);
                $(".entries").append(html);

            }
   });
```